# Unable to update to latest release

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

Attempting to update from 21.10 to 22.04 using `do-release-upgrade`, and receiving an error about needing to install all available updates first. The packages are `gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0`, `gir1.2-webkit2-4.0`, `libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18`, and `libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37`. However, attempting to update them through `apt` results in a message saying those packages were held back.

I've seen suggestions for others with similar problems of held back packages to just delete them (likely for different packages), however, I have no idea what these packages are for, and if I were to delete them, `apt` would also remove some important packages too:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
chrome-gnome-shell evolution evolution-data-server
evolution-plugin-bogofilter evolution-plugin-pstimport evolution-plugins
gdm3 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 gnome-control-center
gnome-initial-setup gnome-online-accounts gnome-remote-desktop gnome-shell
gnome-shell-extension-appindicator gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng
gnome-shell-extension-prefs gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock gnome-tweaks
gnome-user-docs libedataserverui-1.2-3 libevolution libgoa-backend-1.0-1
libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libyelp0 mutter ubuntu-docs
ubuntu-session yelp zenity
```

Attempting to install one of those packages results in similar issues of having important packages removed.

Short of backing up important files, wiping the system, and installing a fresh copy of 22.04, anything I can do to upgrade?

EDIT: As per comment request, version information of the four packages:

```
gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0:
  Installed: 2.34.4-0ubuntu0.21.10.1
  Candidate: 2.36.3-0ubuntu0.21.10.1
  Version table:
     2.36.3-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.34.4-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.34.0-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main amd64 Packages

    gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:
      Installed: 2.34.4-0ubuntu0.21.10.1
      Candidate: 2.36.3-0ubuntu0.21.10.1
      Version table:
         2.36.3-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 500
            500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 Packages
            500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security/main amd64 Packages
     *** 2.34.4-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 100
            100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
         2.34.0-1ubuntu1 500
            500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main amd64 Packages
libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:
  Installed: 2.34.4-0ubuntu0.21.10.1
  Candidate: 2.36.3-0ubuntu0.21.10.1
  Version table:
     2.36.3-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.34.4-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.34.0-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main amd64 Packages

libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:
  Installed: 2.34.4-0ubuntu0.21.10.1
  Candidate: 2.36.3-0ubuntu0.21.10.1
  Version table:
     2.36.3-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.34.4-0ubuntu0.21.10.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.34.0-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/main amd64 Packages
```

I've never used `apt-mark` so there shouldn't be issues there, and I always use `full-upgrade` for updates. All third party PPAs have been commented out.

Comment: You haven't provided any package versions (*which allow us to check they're updated, your software lists are up-to-date etc*), but are any from PPAs which create issues?, you have no *holds* on packages (`apt-mark` etc), and have attempted a `apt full-upgrade` to ensure all upgrades are applied (not just an `apt upgrade`).  For us to be most helpful though; full messages are required.

Comment: @guiverc is exactly right. You must compare your installed versions of each package with the correct version in the Ubuntu repositories. There's a version conflict *somewhere*. The only upgrade (not-reinstall) path goes through locating that wrong-version package(s) and returning it (them) to the stock Ubuntu version. It's not difficult to do, and you seem to have only a few packages to check.

Comment: Your choice is: upgrade and try to debug; or wipe clean and install fresh. In my experience; debugs can take weeks; a fresh install takes 20 minutes and has proven to be guaranteed effective. :-)

Comment: @guiverc - Edited to add requested information

Answer (score 0):

Given that resolving version conflicts would have taken me down a giant rabbit hole (4 packages turned into at least 50 as the dependencies needed different versions as well), and I didn't want to reinstall the entire system, I thought I'd try something else.

Every time I run `apt update` and see the number of packages able to be upgraded, then thinking about how `do-release-upgrade` checks for any packages that need upgrading first, I thought, why not comment out every single line in `sources.list` and all files in `sources.list.d`? I did just that, and ran `apt update` again. No packages to upgrade. Good. Then I ran `do-release-upgrade` and it worked without a problem.

Enabling everything I commented out from the `sources.list` files, I completed the remaining upgrades, and I now have 22.04 with no held packages.

I don't know if this method can be done in every single case, but it seems like the way to go in the future for me, if I run into this issue again.